# Is there something like Glimpse for ASP.NET that tolerates iframes?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, diagnostics

I'm working on a complex ASP.NET web site and it uses lots of iframes all in a fixed 1024 by 768 container, so I'm not able to use [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) like I want to.

My goals are primarily to quickly see the sequence of major execution points as I traverse a particular interaction with the system.  In other words, if I'm reproducing an issue, I'd like something to be showing me the sequence of ASPX pages that are being hit and all the calls to the project's class libraries as well.

Is there anything out there suited to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A profiler should provide what you are looking for, take your pick from the list below:

- Visual Studio 2012 Professional, Premium and Ultimate include a memory and diagnostic profiler - free, depending upon if you have the correct version already
- [SpeedTrace Pro](http://profiler-and-tracer.com/) - costs money, but has a free trial
- [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=unmet_need&utm_campaign=antsperformanceprofiler&gclid=CI7wyu7JjboCFcuZ4Aod-SUAMA) - costs money, but has a free trial
- [Telerik JustTrace](http://www.telerik.com/campaigns/justtrace/vault-memory-performance-profiler.aspx?gclid=CP-u4YHKjboCFQik4AodhB8A4A) - costs money, but has a free trial